# Linq union two tables where on has an extra column

Tags: c#, linq, union

I am using a `Union` to combine two tables `audit` and `message`.  They both have all the same column names except `audit` has an extra column called `deleteDate`. I am try to use a `Union` to merge both table where if `deleteDate` does not exist, than it sets the `DeleteDate` method to null.  I commented out what I am trying to get to work.  When I uncomment the code, I get an error.  Is there a work around? Here is my code

```
    var audit = from a in _Audit.GetAll()
                       .Where(a => a.PInt == pInt && a.CreateDate < startDate && (endDate == null || endDate > a.CreateDate))
                       select new
                       {
                           a.MInt,
                           a.MId,
                           a.Desc,
                           a.PString,
                           a.PType,
                           a.MType,
                           a.CreateDate,
                           //    a.DeleteDate,
                           a.PInt
                       };

    var message = from a in _Message.GetAll()
           .Where(a => a.PartnerInt == partnerInt && a.CreateDate < startDate && (endDate == null || endDate > a.CreateDate))
                  select new
                  {
                      a.MInt,
                      a.MId,
                      a.Desc,
                      a.PString,
                      a.PType,
                      a.MType,
                      a.CDate,
                      a.PInt
                  };

    var test = from a in audit.Union(message)
               select new AuditMessagesGroup
               {
                   MInt = a.Int,
                   MId = a.Id,
                   Desc = a.Desc,
                   PString = a.PString,
                   PType = a.PayloadType,
                   MessageType = a.MType,
                   CreateDate = a.CreateDate,
         //          DeleteDate = a.DeleteDate != null ? a.DeleteDate : null,
                   PInt = a.PInt

               };
```

Here is the error

```
    Error   CS1929  'IQueryable<<anonymous type: int MInt, Guid 

MId, string Desc, string PString, string PType, 

MTypes MType, DateTime CreateDate, DateTime DeleteDate, int? 

PInt>>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best 

extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Union<<anonymous type: int 

MInt, Guid MId, string Desc, string PString, string 

PType, MTypes MType, DateTime CreateDate, int? PInt>>

(ParallelQuery<<anonymous type: int MInt, Guid MId, string 

Desc, string PString, string PType, MTypes 

MType, DateTime CreateDate, int? PInt>>, IEnumerable<<anonymous 

type: int MInt, Guid MId, string Desc, string 

PString, string PType, MTypes MType, DateTime 

CreateDate, int? PInt>>)' requires a receiver of type 

'ParallelQuery<<anonymous type: int MInt, Guid MId, string 

Desc, string PString, string PType, MTypes 

MType, DateTime CreateDate, int? PInt>>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO you can't. Basic criteria on union is that column count must match b/w tables. You can generate a dummy column though to bypass. like

considering `a.DeleteDate` is `DateTime` in `audit` change your `message` to be

```
var message = from a in _Message.GetAll()
       .Where(a => a.PartnerInt == partnerInt && a.CreateDate < startDate && (endDate == null || endDate > a.CreateDate))
              select new
              {
                  a.MInt,
                  a.MId,
                  a.Desc,
                  a.PString,
                  a.PType,
                  a.MType,
                  a.CDate,
                  DateTime.Now, // a dummy column
                  a.PInt
              };
```

Then you can perform the `UNION`

Comment: No, it is not a "basic criteria on union is that column count must match b/w tables". It is not enough that the column count is the same, nor is it enough that the column types match either. The types on both sides of the union must be the same.

Comment: @Enigmativity, yes but in this specific context that would be the issue; that column count in either side of union doesn't match.

Comment: No, it's not. The type on each side must match. Just getting the column count right will do **nothing**.

Answer (score 1):

To make `.Union(...)` work the anonymous type **must** be exactly the same - and that requires it to have the exact same number of fields, with the exact same types, with the exact same names.

So, from your queries, I think you need this:

```
var audit =
    from a in _Audit
        .GetAll()
        .Where(a => a.PInt == pInt)
        .Where(a => a.CreateDate < startDate)
        .Where(a => endDate == null || endDate > a.CreateDate)
    select new
    {
        a.MInt,
        a.MId,
        a.Desc,
        a.PString,
        a.PType,
        a.MType,
        a.CreateDate,
        a.DeleteDate,
        a.PInt
    };

var message =
    from a in _Message
        .GetAll()
        .Where(a => a.PartnerInt == partnerInt)
        .Where(a => a.CreateDate < startDate)
        .Where(a => endDate == null || endDate > a.CreateDate)
    select new
    {
        a.MInt,
        a.MId,
        a.Desc,
        a.PString,
        a.PType,
        a.MType,
        CreateDate = a.CDate,
        DeleteDate = (DateTime?)null,
        a.PInt
    };
```

I can't tell for sure what the types are of each table, but hopefully that's pretty close.

It is possible that you'll need to pull the records in to memory using `.ToArray()` followed by a new `.Select(...)` to get the field types to align, but assuming they are already the same it should work fine.